# Facebook Audience SDK

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to display Banner Ads in any of my android Apps the last couple of weeks.

I do get the Test-Banner if I add my device as testdevice. 
I do get Interstitial Ads

But I do not get any Banner.
Logcat gives me **"I/Facebook Error﹕ frequent load"** on any of my devices (5 tested), also tested deifferent advertiser ids from facebook.

Does anybody else have this issues?

**EDIT:**
After installing the facebook app on any of these test devices I do get Banner Ads delivered.
Why do they only deliver ads to users with the facebook ad installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Audience Network requires the fb app to be installed on the device to delivery ads as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/faq#a12. There's also a minimum time interval in between ad requests made from the same placement. If you make a new request within that interval, you'll see the frequent load error. Hope this helps!